# Reducing linq and convert C#2005

Tags: c#

I want to  reducing linq code below and convert C# 2005

```
private void cmdCaculator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     int rowcount = gridView1.RowCount;

     Thread myThr = new Thread(() =>
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
          {
               x *=i;
          }
     });
     myThr.Start();    
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. `x` will be always 0. do you want to calculate factorial? you should start `i` from `1`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no LINQ in that code - just a lambda expression. You can use an anonymous method instead:

```
private void cmdCaculator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     int rowcount = gridView1.RowCount;

     Thread myThr = new Thread(delegate ()
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
          {
               x *= i;
          }
     });
     myThr.Start();    
}
```

However, I would *strongly* recommend that you update your toolchain. By restricting yourself to C# 2 you're missing out on *lots* of massively useful features.

Comment: I'm studying language linq, I did not know much about linq, so I need the example of LINQ to learn, I thank you

Comment: @user3577283: I don't know what you mean. Your code has nothing to do with LINQ. There's no LINQ to remove, and nothing in the code where LINQ would reasonably be introduced.